# To Do list updates an empty string in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started an internship I have to build a to-do list using NEXT JS. but the problem arises that the app also updates an empty string. I have to work on this and have more than 20 hours to dig up a solution. I wasn't able to solve it. I tried passing some parameters but it's not working.

```
import { useState } from "react"
import '../styles/globals.css'

const index=()=> {
    const [userinput,setuserinput]=useState("")
    const [todolist,settodolist]=useState([])

    const handlechange=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(e.target.value!=""){
            setuserinput(e.target.value)
        }
    }

    const handlesubmit=(e)=> {
        settodolist([
            userinput,
            ...todolist
        ])

        e.preventDefault()
    }

const handledelete=(todo)=>{
 const updatedelete=todolist.filter(todoitem => todolist.indexOf(todoitem) != todolist.indexOf(todo))
 settodolist(updatedelete)
}

    return(
        <div className="FLEX">
            <h3 className="heading">Welcome to Next JS To Do app</h3>
            <form className="FORM">
               <div className="Wrap">
                    <input type="text" onChange={handlechange} placeholder="Enter a todo item" className="INPUT"></input>
                    <button onClick={handlesubmit} className="Button">Submit</button>
               </div>
            </form>
            <ul>
                {
                    todolist.length>=1?todolist.map((todo,idx)=>{
                        return <li key={idx}>{todo} <button onClick={(e)=>{
                            e.preventDefault()
                            handledelete(todo)
                        }}>Delete</button></li>
                    }):"Enter a Todo List"
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default index
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `value` prop to your `input` element:

```
<input type="text" value={userinput} onChange={handlechange} placeholder="Enter a todo item" className="INPUT"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is asking to prevent the user from entering a todo item with no name. In this case, do as the previous comment mentioned and add the value prop to the input:

`<input type="text" value={userinput} onChange={handlechange} placeholder="Enter a todo item" className="INPUT"></input>`

then add this to your handleSubmit function:

```
  const handlesubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (userinput != '') {
      settodolist([userinput, ...todolist]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: By looking at the code, it's extremely likely that he is using javascript, so having ```e: any``` would cause a problem since that is a typscript feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to submit an empty item to the todo list, check if the userinput is empty or not.

```
    const handlesubmit = (e) => {
        if (userinput === "") return

        settodolist([
            userinput,
            ...todolist
        ])

        e.preventDefault()
    }
```